# MediaWiki Template Parsing with HTML Tags

Tags: iframe, mediawiki

How do I parse wiki markup within  tags?

For example, I'm creating a template to insert an iframe into my personal wiki page:

Template:iframelink contains:

```
<html>
<iframe src="http://www.{{{1}}}.com"></iframe>
</html>
```

However, I can't pass anything to {{{1}}} because it's within the <html> tags.

What work-arounds can I use to be able to expand {{{1}}} within the html tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly something like this:

```
<html>
<iframe src="http://www.</html>{{{1}}}<html>.com"></iframe>
</html>
```

You may want to investigate a more general solution like:

http://www.mediawikiwidgets.org/Iframe

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into an iFrame plugin

Comment: Hm. I thought that this was way too simple to work. At least as of 2022... it doesn't. The HTML tags are rendered as, well, normal ASCII text, without being interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

If you have permission to make technical changes (or can influence those that can) you could add an extension to support HTML. My favourite is [RawMsg](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aRawMsg) because the administrators keep control over what HTML is permitted.